# Array changes when not modified

Tags: c#, arrays

I'm a beginner and this problem is probably very obvious, but I've been having a lot of trouble with it.

In the following code, when i2 is set to i, i does not change when i2 subsequently changes.  However, when arr2 is set to arr, arr is also updated when arr2 subsequently changes.

Why is that? What is the difference?

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    int i = 5;
    int i2 = i;

    Console.WriteLine(i);      //output is 5

    i2 = i - 2;

    Console.WriteLine(i);      //output is 5

//------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    int[] arr = { 5 };
    int[] arr2 = arr;

    Console.WriteLine(arr[0]);    //output is 5

    arr2[0] = arr[0] -2;

    Console.WriteLine(arr[0]);    //output is 3

//---------------------------------------------------------------------

    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Comment: Please read [Value Types and Reference Types](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t63sy5hs.aspx). 'int' is a value type and an 'array' (int[]) is a reference type.

Comment: Also consider indicating the language or context in the subject line of your question. This general advice will help draw attention from folks who can offer the most relevant responses.

Answer (score 2):

Statement

```
int[] arr2 = arr;
```

doesn't create new array object, it just assigns reference to `arr`. That's why when you modify `arr2`, `arr` is also modified. Situation with int is different because int (or Int32) is actually struct, not a class, and memory for integers is allocated on the stack, not in the heap. More details here: [C# Concepts: Value vs Reference Types](http://www.albahari.com/valuevsreftypes.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

In C#, arrays are reference types. When you assigned arr2=arr, you told arr2 to use the reference of arr in memory.

See here for more information:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2z4khca9.aspx

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hyfeyz71.aspx

Answer (score 1):

In your first case as below `INT` is a `struct` type which is a `value type` and thus will be bitwise value copied every time you assign to other variable and thus in your below code both `i` and `i2` has a separate copy of it and changing one doesn't affect other.

```
    int i = 5;
    int i2 = i;
```

For second case as below `Array` is a `Class` (Inherited from base type `System.Aray`) which by design is a `reference type` and so you are just assigning the reference of array to other array variable. So changing one will affect other as well since both the referring to same array object present in Heap memory.

```
    int[] arr = { 5 };
    int[] arr2 = arr;
```

See array documentation in MSDN 
[Array Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.array(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Hey In the first case those are variables,As a result those variables are not related to each other by memory mappings.
Where as in the second case it is assigning of the Reference of the array because of that the answer is 3.And any changes you make on arr will be found on arr2 also.